# Custom Twitter, G+, Facebook buttons

Tags: html, css, facebook, twitter, google-plus

Google, Twitter, Facebook all seem to have their own styles, colors and worst - sizes. Is there any way to use custom images WHILE also retaining the share 'counts'? A simple API or workaround for all 3 services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These API's usually render markup to your page which can be *targeted* & *styled* through `CSS`. So, implementing your own `CSS` that targets the rendered markup may be the simplest and cleanest approach.

Another option is to create your own `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript` that acts as a `fascade` between the underlying API (Facebook, G+, Twitter) and the client.

Answer (score 0):

These will return simple JSON responses with counts for property of re-Tweets & Likes for a specific URL:

```
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=SOME_URL_HERE
http://graph.facebook.com/SOME_URL_HERE
```

Examples:
TWITTER API CALL:

http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://stackoverflow.com

:: JSON RESPONSE:

{"count":4504,"url":"http://stackoverflow.com/"}

FACEBOOK GRAPH CALL:

http://graph.facebook.com/http://stackoverflow.com

:: JSON RESPONSE:

{
   "id": "http://stackoverflow.com",
   "shares": 7004,
   "comments": 3
}

Currently there is no public API method for Google...